# Suitecrm http 500 error for form submit

Tags: sugarcrm, http-error, suitecrm

I am using suitecrm 7.9.1

Whenever I create a record (in any module e.g. Contacts, Leads, Accounts etc) and click "Save" button to submit form then I get 500 error.

Other custom/default forms are working fine and this issue only occurring on production server.

Comment: share the last lines of log file of Error Log.

Comment: Thank you for your reply  .  Iconv extension was missing , due to which faced http 500 error ... Installed iconv for cpanel , its working fine now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that you have proper .htaccess and permission on server should be 755. if that still doesn't resolve your issue then share Sugar and server error log.